# "The resource cannot be found" when I hit F5 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, server-error

I have a .NET 3.5 web application that I am trying to run in my local development environment.

Every time I hit F5 to run the application, I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Default.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3614
```

I am running Visual Studio 2010. This web application runs perfectly on our production server, but I can't seem to get it running on my local development box.

Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I just experienced the same problem.  This seems to have occurred following the temporary disabling of the Productivity Power Tools.  So much for productivity.  Did you find any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's looking for a local web server, because your URL is /Default.aspx.  You might need to point it to the actual server.

Comment: But I am just trying to run it directly from Visual Studio on my local machine.

Comment: Also, if your application is .Net 3.5, you might be having a problem since VS is stating that it's version 2.0